# Postfix : unsupported dictionary type: texthash

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I installed Postfix on my server and configured it like i have it on an ubuntu machine running.

I added a map to rewrite the sender address (which i have to do because i use mailjet.com as outbound mailserver) to the main.cf

```
smtp_generic_maps=texthash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

the generic file looks like following

```
root@physical1  physical1@mydomain.com
```

When i restart postfix i get following error message in the syslog

```
Jan 12 23:51:04 physical1 postfix/smtp[26902]: fatal: dict_open: 
unsupported dictionary type: texthash:  Is the postfix-texthash package installed?
```

Has anyone a clue why this is happening? I searched if there's a postfix-texthash package but i've not found one

**Update**

```
postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
hash
internal
nis
proxy
regexp
sdbm
static
tcp
unix
```

Postfix Version : 2.7.1-1+squeeze1

Comment: Please update with the output of `postconf -m`.

Comment: And it would be _very_ useful to know the Postfix version and the distribution name/version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running Postfix version 2.7. `texthash` was introduced in Postfix 2.8 with the new `postscreen` server: http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html.

You're best off just using `hash:` and running `postmap` on the file, as SvenW suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
smtp_generic_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

and issue the command `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` before restarting postfix in order to generate the hash file.

Comment: This is a workaround to get an equivalent solution. But it is not the exact solution to the question.

Comment: @mailq: Yes, but lacking any further information about the OPs system, it's the only solution that's likely available without further work, and while it doesn't really matter for such a short map file, I consider using a hashed one the better solution anyway.

Comment: That's true and would be my choice, too.